# Postman “Could not get any response” http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_chain

Tags: response, postman

I am using Postman for request and response using local host, even turning off ssl from setting in postman still no response. Any idea?

Comment: Not enough content in your question.

Comment: I am executing my code using RStudio, and suppose to get a "GET" response using localhost (http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_chain). Using FLASK framework, and code I mentioned is (@app.route('/get_chain', methods = ['GET'])
def get_chain():
    response = {'chain': blockchain.chain,
                'length': len(blockchain.chain)}
    return jsonify(response), 200

#Running the App
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port = 5000)

Comment: When your comment is more detailed than your question, that’s a problem. Update the original question with these details.

Answer (score -1):

Restart your localhost server and try again.

Answer (score -1):

While setting up a Socket.io connection using Postman, I encountered the error `Could not connect to http://127.0.0.1:4000?someKey=some@value`. The issue stemmed from the fact that the values needed to be URI encoded. Typically, Postman autonomously encodes values in HTTP requests. However, in the case of the socket connection, I encountered this error. The problem was resolved as soon as I manually URL-encoded the values.